# ajax cannot post back node express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

i am using Ajax and submitting a form. my form contains a image file which i am getting by input type file and some values from input fields. when i pass only single variable for testing is it return to **success:** . but when i pass form it shows error in console that it cannot post(404 not found). and shows [Object object ]in **error:** if i enable page refresh it shows the output on **/cropImg** route like this: {file_name:'filename'} i don't what i am doing wrong. i have tried many things but nothing is working its been like 3 days i am stuck here..

**my Ajax form submissions**

```
$('#cover_file_form').submit(function(e) {
        var form_data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        //data: {mydata:'akmal'},
        //data: JSON.stringify({ "objectData":form_data}),
        //async: false,
        // dataType: 'json',
        //contentType: "application/json",
        processData: false,
        success: function(ret_data) {
            alert('success'+ret_data.file_name);
        },
        error: function(r_data) {
         alert('error'+r_data);
        }
       });
    return false;

 });
```

**and route file (routes/index.js)**

```
 app.post('/cropImg',function(req,res){
//      // get the temporary location of the file
     //var tmp_path = req.files['file_browse_cover'].path;
//      //using graphics magick for cropping
//      // gm(tmp_path)
//      //  .resize(500,278, "!")
//      //  .crop(parseInt(req.body.InputWidth),parseInt(req.body.InputHeight), parseInt(req.body.InputLeft), parseInt(req.body.InputTop))
//      //  .write(__dirname + "/public/images-esct/cropped/"+req.files['file_browse_cover'].name  , function (err) {

//      //     if(err) throw err;
//      //          console.log(err);
//      //  });
//      //sending file name
    //fs.readFile(thisfl.path, function (err, data) {
    //  var newPath = __dirname + "\\eac_uploads\\" + thisfl.originalFilename;
    //  fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            //res.send({ some: JSON.stringify({response:'tmp_path'}) });
            //res.send({file_name:'akmal'});
            // });
    //});
    res.send({file_name: req.files['file_browse_cover'].name});

 })
```

Comment: Use a tool like fiddler or another network inspector built into the browser to view the request sent to the server. Then validate the request URL. Looks like the URL is wrong.

Comment: as you can see i have commented out the rest of code in app.post() i am cropping and upload image using graphicsmagick module. it crops and uploads the image .. i have already mentioned that if i use simple variables for testing it works. i think the problem is some thing like Json.. may b i am not sending response correctly thats why its not working @DonJayamanne

Comment: Try res.json(...) instead of res.send(...)